# What happens when an Inquisitor's alignment changes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment

According to the [rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor):

> An inquisitor’s alignment must be within one step of her deity’s,
>   along either the law/chaos axis or the good/evil axis.

So what happens when the alignment of an inquisitor changes from lawful good (assuming that is the alignment of his deity) over time to lawful evil (or anything else which is more than one step apart)? Does he lose all his spells? Can he just change his deity? Can he become atheist and still have his spells?

A RAW answer would be great!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Pathfinder SRD in the [Inquisitor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor#TOC-Ex-Inquisitors) article states:

> **Ex-Inquisitors** 
>   An inquisitor who slips into corruption or changes to a prohibited alignment loses all spells and the judgment ability. She cannot thereafter gain levels as an inquisitor until she atones (see the atonement spell description). An inquisitor who becomes an ex-inquisitor can, with the GM’s permission, take the heretic archetype, replacing her class abilities with the appropriate archetype abilities. If the character atones or joins a different faith, she loses her heretic abilities and regains her previous inquisitor class abilities.

Simply this is the RAW and should contain the necessary answers.

Comment: Someone must have cast a blindness-deafness spell on me. Thank you for removing it. :)